# Class & Object classes in ruby

Tags: ruby

I am beginner for ruby. here are two different classed `Class` & `Object`. I don't understand the purpose of having `Object`. Objects are those built upon calling class' constructor (or `new` method), then why there is need for separate `Object` class? Please clarify me about `Class` & `Object` classes.

Comment: You can create `Object.new` to get an object that is not an instance of anything but `Object` (and `BasicObject`)

Comment: for now skip that concept,when you will pass 3 or more months in Ruby,you will slowly start to understand that thing. :)

Comment: @JanDvorak yes that I understand. But is there anything additional that belongs to Object in general? Is it just a utility class or, does it have to do anything with feature of an object (instance).

Comment: @OMG is it something making me confuse between object & instance or Object class really have to do something with instance

Comment: @ay89 it's a common superclass. It's good to have a common superclass

Comment: @JanDvorak so any class we create is a subtype of Object, and Class is a class that tells about features of that class (something like reflection in java)

Answer (score 2):

**Everything in ruby is an object**, so is `Class`:

```
irb > Class.is_a? Object
 => true
```

**Every object has a class**, so does `Object`:

```
irb > Object.class === Class
 => true
```

Even `Class` itself has a class:

```
irb > Class.class === Class
 => true
```

Comment: `BasicObject.new.class` => `NoMethodError`

Comment: It still has a class - it's just that the `class` method doesn't exist

Comment: +1 @FrederickCheung `It still has a class - it's just that the class method doesn't exist`. I'd say it still has a class, but it doesn't have the brains to know it. :-)

Answer (score 0):

> why there is need for separate `Object` class?

Your have different classes for `Class` and `Object` because classes and objects are not the same.

In Ruby, everything *is* an object and every object *has* a class, but not every object *is* a class.

This creates a new class:

```
class MyClass
end
```

`MyClass` is a class:

```
MyClass.is_a? Class        #=> true
```

A class object has specific methods, e.g. [`superclass`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Class.html#method-i-superclass). This method is implemented in the [`Class`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Class.html) class and because `MyClass` is a class, it responds to it:

```
MyClass.superclass         #=> Object
```

An instance of `MyClass` on the other hand is not a class:

```
my_instance = MyClass.new  #=> #<MyClass:0x007f7f5c041d10>
my_instance.is_a? Class    #=> false
```

and it doesn't respond to `superclass`:

```
my_instance.superclass     #=> NoMethodError: undefined method `superclass'
```

but of course it *has* a class, namely `MyClass`:

```
my_instance.class          #=> MyClass
```

Both, `MyClass` and `my_instance` are objects:

```
MyClass.is_a? Object       #=> true
my_instance.is_a? Object   #=> true
```

Both respond to methods from the [`Object`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html) class, e.g. [`object_id`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Object.html#method-i-object_id):

```
MyClass.object_id          #=> 70092490725660
my_instance.object_id      #=> 70092490673800
```